# Wordpress multiple widget in single plugin

Tags: plugins, widgets

In my plugin in need to create two widget.
One is :social rank" another is "Profile Rank".

This is the code which i am using here.

```
    <?php
    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'src_load_widgets' );

function src_load_widgets() {
    register_widget( 'Widget_SRC' );
}
function src_load_widgets() {
    register_widget( 'Widget_Rank ' );
}

class Widget_SRC extends WP_Widget {

    function Widget_SRC() {

        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'src', 'description' => __('Several social networks counts and ranking system', 'src') );       
        $control_ops = array( 'width' => 300, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'social-rank' );        
        $this->WP_Widget( 'social-rank', __('Social Rank', 'src'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
    }


    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );   
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );    
        echo $before_widget;

        if ( $title )
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;

        echo do_shortcode('[SocialRank]');      

        echo $after_widget;
    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;

        $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
        return $instance;
    }

    function form( $instance ) {

        $defaults = array( 'title' => __('Social Rank', 'src'));
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); ?>
        <!-- Widget Title: Text Input -->
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e('Title:', 'hybrid'); ?></label>
            <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" style="width:100%;" />
        </p>        

    <?php
    }
}
        class Widget_Rank extends WP_Widget {

            /**
             * Widget setup.
             */
            function Widget_Rank() {
                /* Widget settings. */
                $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'rank', 'description' => __('Display profile rank based on vote & social counts.', 'rank') );

                /* Widget control settings. */
                $control_ops = array( 'width' => 300, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'profile-rank' );

                /* Create the widget. */
                $this->WP_Widget( 'profile-rank', __('Profile Rank', 'rank'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
            }

            /**
             * How to display the widget on the screen.
             */
            function widget( $args, $instance ) {
                extract( $args );

                /* Our variables from the widget settings. */
                $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );

                /* Before widget (defined by themes). */
                echo $before_widget;

                /* Display the widget title if one was input (before and after defined by themes). */
                if ( $title )
                    echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;

                echo do_shortcode('[SocialRank]');

                /* After widget (defined by themes). */
                echo $after_widget;
            }

            /**
             * Update the widget settings.
             */
            function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
                $instance = $old_instance;

                /* Strip tags for title and name to remove HTML (important for text inputs). */
                $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
                return $instance;
            }

            /**
             * Displays the widget settings controls on the widget panel.
             * Make use of the get_field_id() and get_field_name() function
             * when creating your form elements. This handles the confusing stuff.
             */
            function form( $instance ) {

                /* Set up some default widget settings. */
                $defaults = array( 'title' => __('Profile Rank', 'rank'));
                $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); ?>

                <!-- Widget Title: Text Input -->
                <p>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e('Title:', 'hybrid'); ?></label>
                    <input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" style="width:100%;" />
                </p>        

            <?php
            }
        }
         ?>
```

But it is not displaying me second widget.
I have found this but not able to get how to solve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247302/php-namespace-5-3-and-wordpress-widget/5247436#5247436

Comment: I don't see the second Widget class. Where is this `Widget_SRC` that you're trying to register?

Comment: @Soulseekah Can you please check it now

Comment: You can't have 2 functions with the same name `src_load_widgets`...

Comment: Put both `register_widget` calls into one `src_load_widgets` function. And I don't see why it won't work.

Comment: @Soulseekah Done! can you please post answer so i can complete this question with correct solution

Comment: By the way, constructors in PHP5 are done with `function __construct`, no need to be old school, WordPress is PHP5+ anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is absolutely no problem with registering several widgets inside one file. Widgets are separate classes, and unlike other programming languages, PHP will have no problem with your declaring two classes inside one file.

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'src_load_widgets' );

function src_load_widgets() {
    register_widget( 'Widget_SRC' );
    register_widget( 'Widget_Rank ' );
}

class Widget_SRC extends WP_Widget {
    // ...
}

class Widget_Rank extends WP_Widget {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ohh my mistake

```
function load_widgets() {
    register_widget( 'Widget_SRC' );
    register_widget( 'Widget_Rank' );
}
```